# Silverlight limitations regarding database access/multi threading

Tags: .net, database, multithreading, silverlight

Speaking of in-browser (having not much experience with a SL, I can only assume this is a very common usage scenario) SL applications - do they have any programming restrictions with respect to database access and multi-threading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight uses the runtime for Silverlight which is a subset of the .net CLR and it does not include any Data Access classes. To get access to data you will need to make a service call to a webservice or make an Webrequest. This can be automated when you use .NET RIA Services (more info at: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/)

Multithreading is possible, actually all Service calls are by default asynchronous so they are performed in another thread. The easiest way to perform multithreading for a responsive UI is by using the BackgroundWorker